# Multiple strings in LIKE condition - Presto SQL

Tags: sql, presto

I want to query a column in my table using a `LIKE` condition and this works fine-

```
select * from my_table where my_column LIKE '%hello%';
```

But, how do I query this column with multiple strings in my `LIKE` condition? Looking for something like-

```
select * from my_table where my_column LIKE ['%hello%'|'example%'|'%random%'|'%demo'];
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `regexp_like()`:

```
select *
from my_table
where regexp_like(my_column, 'hello|example|random|demo');
```

Comment: Does `regexp_like()` perform as quickly as multiple `LIKE` statements?

Comment: @Stevoisiak … I would expect it to be a wee bit faster.  There is only one function call versus a call for each pattern.  However, it is worth testing on your database.