# SQL - Presto : How to select multiple columns based on LIKE operator?

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a table like this

[image]

and in SQL query I want to select only columns which are matching in where condition, e.g. if I say columns `IN (x,y)` then it should return `x_1, x_2, x_3, y_1, y_2, y_3` columns, like this
[image]

What I tried

First I tried to use cases but the execution of query stopped once first condition has met

```
SELECT id,
CASE
    WHEN 'x' IN ({{ type }}) THEN 
        x_1,x_2,x_3
    WHEN 'y' IN ({{ type }}) THEN 
        y_1,y_2,y_3
    ELSE 'n/a'
END as type
FROM table_name
```

I have also tried some stackoverflow answers but no luck

[sql select with column name like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274594/sql-select-with-column-name-like)

[how to use LIKE with column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398720/how-to-use-like-with-column-name)

[Use * Like operator to search all columns of table in sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46733784/use-like-operator-to-search-all-columns-of-table-in-sql-query)

[SQL query to select columns with exact like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46532153/sql-query-to-select-columns-with-exact-like)

[Like statement across multiple columns in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42630678/like-statement-across-multiple-columns-in-sql)

[Multiple strings in LIKE condition - Presto SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64780028/multiple-strings-in-like-condition-presto-sql)

Answer (score 0):

In short - this is not possible (with pure SQL at least) in Presto/Trino.

SQL in general is not designed to return dynamic column sets. And while some db/query engines may allow some scripting to dynamically generate and execute query (or another option - dynamic pivoting) - Presto/Trino does not. The only option is to use some kind of outside scripting (which seems to already be the case) - i.e. query the columns:

```sql
select *
from  information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'table_name'
   -- AND column_name ... -- maybe filter here
```

And then process the results and then generate the query and execute it.

Or if you already know the columns - just dynamically create the query string.

P.S.

1. The provided query is not a valid one in Presto/Trino (even if you substitute the `{{...}}`)
2. *but the execution of query stopped once first condition has met* - yes, that is exactly how the [CASE](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#case) is designed to work - it executes the first `true` condition and then returns it's matched result. Basically it is SQL way to say `if-else`
3. Another option you might want to consider - pivoting and/or using `maps`:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2, z_1) as (
    values (1,2,3,4,5),
           (1,2,3,4,5),
           (1,2,3,4,5)
)
-- query
select map_filter(
                map(array['x_1', 'x_2', 'y_1', 'y_2', 'z_1'], array[x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2, z_1]),
                (k,v) -> any_match(array['x', 'y'], c -> k like c || '%') -- change array['x', 'y'] to contain needed prefixes
           )
from dataset;
```

Output:

```
            _col0
------------------------------
 {x_2=2, y_1=3, x_1=1, y_2=4}
 {x_2=2, y_1=3, x_1=1, y_2=4}
 {x_2=2, y_1=3, x_1=1, y_2=4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this to return `x` and `y`, but it is not dynamic:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT 'x' as type ,id, x_1 as a,x_2 as b,x_3 as c FROM table_name
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'y' as type ,id, y_1,y_2,y_3 FROM table_name
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'z' as type ,id, z_1,z_2,z_3 FROM table_name
)
SELECT f1.a,f1.b,f1.c, f2.a,f2.b,f2.c
FROM cte f1
INNER JOIN cte f2 ON f1.id=f2.id and f2.type='y'
WHERE f1.type = 'x'
```

Comment: As far as I understand this will result in all columns named the same way (`x_1`, `x_2`, `x_3`).

Comment: Actually `a,b,c`, but column names cannot be dynamic, as you explained in your answer ...